# Javascript - LocalStorage para éste script...?

Tags: javascript

¿Es posible crear un **LocalStorage** para el siguiente script, teniendo en cuenta que debería guardar los parámetros del **script-1** y **script-2** aún cuando se recargue la página...?

---

**NOTA**:
Estoy aprendiendo JS, por cuanto no sé implementar un LocalStorage, aunque he mirado **[Este CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpgaxB)** pero así y todo no logré implementarlo en mi script de práctica...

---

**El script-1** suma y resta los clicks.

**El script-2** clona los divs (ocultos) y los pega en el div "derecha".

Ver demo 100% funcional **[AQUI](https://jsfiddle.net/b85ypx7h/3/)**

Muchas gracias !!!...

```
// Script-1
var clicks=0;function clickME(){clicks += 1;document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML=clicks}
var clicksdos=0;function clickME2(){clicksdos += 1;document.getElementById("clicksdos").innerHTML=clicksdos;

if (clicksdos === 1) {
document.getElementById("mostrar").style.display = "block";
  }
}
if (clicksdos === 0) {
document.getElementById("mostrar").style.display = "none";
  }
function restar() {
if (clicks>0) clicks -= 1;
document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML=clicks;
  }
function restardos() {
if (clicksdos>0) clicksdos -= 1;
document.getElementById("clicksdos").innerHTML=clicksdos;
if(clicksdos === 0){
document.getElementById("mostrar").style.display = "none";
  }
};


// Script-2
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#comp-p1").click(function(){
$("#cont-p1").clone().appendTo(".derecha");
  });
// =============
$("#comp-p2").click(function(){
$("#cont-p2").clone().appendTo(".derecha");
  });
// =============
$("#comp-p3").click(function(){
$("#cont-p3").clone().appendTo(".derecha");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

La API de localStorage permite almacenar cadenas de texo.
Puedes almacenar los valores de **click** y **clickdos** en formato texto mediante el siguiente código:

```
localStorage.setItem('click', click);
localStorage.setItem('clickdos', clickdos);
```

Despues los podras obtener de vuelta y convertirlos a números enteros con

```
if ((localStorage.getItem("click")!=null) && (localStorage.getItem("clickdos")!=null))
{
click=parseInt(localStorage.getItem("click"));
clickdos=parseInt(localStorage.getItem("clickdos"));
}
```

Respecto al contenido del div **.derecha**, lo puedes almacenar mediante

```
localStorage.setItem("html",document.getElementsByClassName("derecha")[0].innerHTML);
```

y obtenerlo de vuelta con

```
document.getElementsByClassName("derecha")[0].innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("html")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Juan. Tu aporte suena muy bién. Mi humilde problema es que no sé cómo implementar el código (la estructura del script), puesto que soy novato en JS y me resulta bastante difícil. Igual te agradezco el aporte. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código añadiendo localStorage sería el siguiente:

```
// Script-1
var clicks=0;function clickME(){clicks += 1;localStorage.setItem('clicks', clicks);document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML=clicks}
var clicksdos=0;function clickME2(){clicksdos += 1;localStorage.setItem('clicksdos', clicksdos);document.getElementById("clicksdos").innerHTML=clicksdos;

if (clicksdos === 1) {
document.getElementById("mostrar").style.display = "block";
    }
}
if (clicksdos === 0) {
document.getElementById("mostrar").style.display = "none";
    }
function restar() {
if (clicks>0) clicks -= 1;
localStorage.setItem('clicks', clicks);
document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML=clicks;
    }
function restardos() {
if (clicksdos>0) clicksdos -= 1;
localStorage.setItem('clicksdos', clicksdos);
document.getElementById("clicksdos").innerHTML=clicksdos;
if(clicksdos === 0){
document.getElementById("mostrar").style.display = "none";
    }
};

// Script-2
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#comp-p1").click(function(){
    $("#cont-p1").clone().appendTo(".derecha");
    localStorage.setItem("html",document.getElementsByClassName("derecha")[0].innerHTML);
  });
  // =============
  $("#comp-p2").click(function(){
    $("#cont-p2").clone().appendTo(".derecha");
    localStorage.setItem("html",document.getElementsByClassName("derecha")[0].innerHTML);
  });
  // =============
  $("#comp-p3").click(function(){
    $("#cont-p3").clone().appendTo(".derecha");
    localStorage.setItem("html",document.getElementsByClassName("derecha")[0].innerHTML);
  });

  if ((localStorage.getItem("clicks")!=null) && (localStorage.getItem("clicksdos")!=null))
  {
    clicks=parseInt(localStorage.getItem("clicks"));
    clicksdos=parseInt(localStorage.getItem("clicksdos"));
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML=clicks;
    document.getElementById("clicksdos").innerHTML=clicksdos;
  }

  if (localStorage.getItem("html")!=null)
  {
    document.getElementsByClassName("derecha")[0].innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("html")
  }

});
```

Saludos

Comment: Hola Juan. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, es muy buena, aunque no sé cómo arreglar algunos errores del LocalStorage de tu código, ya que aunque borre (restar) los divs de la derecha (y los contadores se pongan en "0"), al recargar la página los divs agregados a la derecha (que ya fueron borrados), aún siguen ahí (no desaparecen), y tampoco se almacena el div "mostrar". No encuento la solución, la verdad. Ver ejemplo activo en el siguiente link: https://jsfiddle.net/j7xqe2wu/

Comment: Aqui lo tienes https://jsfiddle.net/kzanj0q5/

Comment: Hola Juan_m_2 muchas gracias. He realizado mejoras en el script (ha cambiado), y acabo de publicar una nueva pregunta. No consigo resolverlo... https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/255114/javascript-arreglar-mis-errores-en-localstorage